# What do the lines for root, sudo and wheel in sudoers mean?

Tags: sudo, configuration

I am trying to understand the sudoers file, but I have a few things that I don't understand.

This line:

```
root ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

Users in `root` on any host (what does host mean, can you give me the real example) can run any command as any user.

What would happen if I deleted this line?

And if I added this line: `username=ALL(ALL) ALL`, does it mean, that username has the same permissions as root because both of them have the same settings?

I also have a line with `%sudo ALL=(ALL) ALL`, but if I list the groups I cannot see any group called sudo.

And I also have a line `%wheel ALL=(ALL) ALL`, but why do I have this line and the line with sudo? Aren't these lines the same?

Comment: There is a spelling error in “username=ALL(ALL) ALL” should be “username ALL=(ALL) ALL”

Answer (score 2):

The hostname can be specified in the `sudoers` file as a specific host or a set of hosts.  This allows an administrator to distribute a single copy of the file to multiple hosts without needing to tailor each file for each host.  A user on one host may have `sudo` access to a particular command only, while the same user has `sudo` access to another command or set of commands on another host.  The `sudoers` files on both host could be left identical.

You should not delete the line that gives root the ability to use `sudo`.  Allowing root to use `sudo` means allowing somebody that is already logged in as root to execute a command as another user easily (and also have it logged, for auditing).

A line saying `username=ALL(ALL) ALL` would contain a syntax error.  Using `username ALL=(ALL) ALL` would give the user `username` the ability to execute `sudo` to run any command.

The `sudo` group may not exist on your system.  There is nothing stopping you from creating it though, and to add users that should have full `sudo` access to that group.  This facility allows you to administrate `sudo` access by adding and removing users to the named group, so no editing of the `sudoers` file is needed to add or to remove the `sudo` access for a user.

The `wheel` group is mostly used on BSD systems, and is traditionally the primary group for the root user on those systems.  Again, your system may not have this group.

See also

- [The wheel group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheel_(computing)) (Wikipedia)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What does it mean root user? Is it user with same permissions as root?

Comment: @J.Doe All Unix systems has a root user (also sometimes called the "superuser").  The root user have no restrictions, can read and delete any file on the system and install software etc.  You should not be using the root user's account for much, and only for very brief periods of time. See e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superuser and http://www.linfo.org/root.html

Comment: @J.Doe You should probably familiarise yourself with the system as an ordinary non-root user before you start changing the `sudoers` file. Making mistakes in that file could have serious or at least very inconvenient consequences.

Comment: If root can everything, why I have this line in sudoers? And what is difference between username ALL=(ALL) ALL and user in group ALL=(ALL) ALL?

Comment: @J.Doe I believe I covered those points in my answer. `sudo` would still deny root from using `sudo` if you deleted that line (it has nothing to do with what root can or cannot do as superuser, it only has to do with the logic of the `sudo` program). The other difference that you ask about is a difference in how you administrate `sudo` privileges. I mentioned this too. You either add users individually to the `sudoers` file, but this may be to bothersome on large systems, so it may be easier to add users to a special `sudo` group.

Comment: @J.Doe Remember that `sudo` logs every command that you execute through it. This is vitally important in places where you need to keep track of who did what as what user. Allowing root to use `sudo` means being able to log `sudo` access by whoever is logged in as root at that point.  It also allows root to execute programs as _another_ user, for example `sudo -u dbuser systemctl start database_server` or whatever.  There may even be system maintenance scripts that _rely_ on this.

Comment: Thanks. I wanna to try some examples in real life, but not today. What is better, if I wanna have normal user? Add line under root line (username ALL=(ALL) ALL) or add user to group wheel and add this line %wheel ALL=(ALL) ALL? Both options are same, aren't? Sorry for stupidy questions, I am little slowmind.

Comment: Your asked “What does it mean root user? Is it user with same permissions as root?”. Yes because root is root. Not root is equivalent to root. root user = root.

Comment: use `visudo`, to edit /etc/sudoers. You can use any editor you like, by typing `EDITOR="«my favourite editor»" sudo visudo`. It will warn you if you are about to do something to break sudo (that will lock you out).

Comment: @J.Doe For testing purposes, add your user using `username ALL=(ALL) ALL` to the `sudoers` file using `visudo` as  ctrl-alt-delor mentioned.

Comment: ´Both options are same, aren't they?´ Sorry, if you already answered. But if some user can run any commands and some group can do the same thing, it looks like same thing.

Comment: @J.Doe Yes, I did answer this.  The difference is how you administrate the `sudo` access.  Do you want to give users `sudo` access by adding their individual usernames to the `sudoers` file, or would it be easier to add the user to a special `sudo` group on the system?  This is the only difference. It's feature that gives convenience and that caters to different administrative situations.

Comment: So difference is just in clarity? Before, when I asked you which options is better, you answered: "...For testing purposes...". It means, that any the form of entry, where user(me) has ability to run any command is bad? How do you set the permissions to your account that you use?

Comment: @J.Doe I don't use Linux. I use OpenBSD.  OpenBSD does not have `sudo` we have [something else](https://man.openbsd.org/doas). I suggested adding your user to `sudoers` because that is _quick_ and _easy_, i.e. the best option for testing something out.